# Prove that $\log \left(\dfrac{\sin (x+iy)} {\sin (x-iy)}\right)= 2i \tan^{-1} (\cot x \tanh y)$.

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $$\log \left(\dfrac{\sin (x+iy)} {\sin (x-iy)}\right)= 2i \tan^{-1} (\cot x \tanh y)$$

Comment: What have you done so far to solve it?

Comment: So go ahead and prove it.

Comment: Questions posted here should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework. It can make people wonder if you copied a question without understanding it, so that no question is present in your own mind. That is probably the reason someone down-voted your question and voted to close it. With newbie posters, they ought to explain that here in comments, but usually they don't.

Comment: [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Like Elnur said, it would be good to explain the steps you have tried. This is because others will then know exactly what you are thinking and what their answer should address. When giving hints, it is important to gauge what the OP might be able to fill in by themselves and what they might not.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a\pm ib=\sin(x\pm iy)$

Which is $=\sin x\cosh y\pm i\cos x\sin h y$

Comment: I wouldn't say "Let $a\pm ib=\text{[something]}$" unless I'm going to use the new notation introduced there, the $a$ and the $b. \qquad$

Comment: @Michael, you mean $$a,b$$ should be mentioned as real?

Comment: What I meant was that I wouldn't introduce new notation unless I'm going to use it.